# how to get all combination of two dates with 20 minutes difference in php/codeigniter or either mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have this  in my db:

[image]

I want to display doctor available time in in select box with difference of 20 minutes like from

**2015-10-12 02:00:00** to **2015-10-12 04:00:00**
what i need is

```
02:00:00
02:20:00
02:40:00
03:00:00
03:20:00
03:40:00
04:00:00
```

I tried this `select '2015-10-12 02:00:00' + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE` but it shows only one values i need all possible combinations.

Comment: Use mysql **between** :-  **BETWEEN date1 AND date2**

Comment: @Rahautos can you please show me example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `DateTime()`, `DateInterval()`, and `DatePeriod()` to loop through that date period every 20 minutes and output the time. Note, we have to add a minute to the end time because `DatePeriod` does *not* include the last end time by default. Adding that minute will get the last time to be included.

```
$start    = new DateTime('2015-10-12 02:00:00');
$end      = (new DateTime('2015-10-12 04:00:00'))->modify('+1 minute');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT20M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('H:i:s');
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/449051)

Comment: This is easier to do in the application layer, unless the database has a table containing all the time slots.

Comment: @john this code works fine. but why this shows error in editor. ?

Comment: I can't say for sure but your editor may not be aware of some of the syntax this code is using. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using dream viewer. :p

Comment: Ahh, that's not the best editor by a long shot especially for PHP code. That would explain why it can't handle it.

Comment: I'm a big fan of PHPStorm but it isn't cheap. Netbeans might be the best free one.